# Integrate zoom in product Photos modal in Magento2

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, modal-popup, modal

How Can I integrate zoom in product sheet modal in magento 2
[image: Product images Modal]

Comment: Can someone help me ?

Comment: Can you please try bigger image ?